# Trasnfering file from C# WPF to C client

Tags: c#, c, wpf, file-transfer, fwrite

I am trying to pass a text file from a C# server based with wpf to a C client I made.

For some reason in the C part when I try to write into the file it says

> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

in the `fwrite` function.

What could be causing this?

I checked the file size sent and it was alright, both sides printed the same size and from the C# side it says it all been sent but the writing to file on the C side fails.

C# code for transfer:

```
 public static void SendFile(Socket clientSocket, string fileName)
    {
        string folder = @"C:\Users\Roy\source\repos\GUI243\GUI243\";
        string fullPath = folder + fileName;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullPath);
        long file_size = fi.Length;
        byte[] preBuffer;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                writer.Write(file_size);
                MessageBox.Show(file_size.ToString());
            }
            preBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        clientSocket.Send(preBuffer); // sending size
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            byte[] message = new Byte[4096];
            int size_passed = 0;
            do
            {
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(size_passed, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                reader.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                clientSocket.Send(message);
                size_passed += 4096;
                file_size -= message.Length;
            } while (file_size > 0);
        }
      
       // clientSocket.SendFile(fullPath, preBuffer, null, TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread);
        MessageBox.Show("File has been sent!");
    }
}
```

C client:

```
/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for receiving a length of data from the client
Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *buf - holds a pointer to the buffer that needs to update
             bufsize - the length of the buffer

Return Value : returns TRUE when the data is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
============================================
*/
bool recv_raw(SOCKET sock, void* buf, int bufsize)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int num = recv(sock, pbuf, bufsize, 0);
        if (num <= 0) { return false; }
        pbuf += num;
        bufsize -= num;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : receives the length of the file and updates it

Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *filesize - holds a pointer to the size of the buffer that needs to update
             filesize_len - the length of the file size pointer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the size is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
===================================================
*/
bool recv_file_len(SOCKET sock, long* filesize)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, filesize, sizeof(*filesize))) { return false; }
    return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : writes to the lua file the data from the file
that was received in the socket
Parameters : sock - the socket between the client and server
             *f - the file to write the data received to
Return Value : returns TRUE when everything was written to the file.
returns FALSE if there's no data received or detected a socket problem.
===================================================
*/
bool receive_and_write_file(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    long filesize;//size of address
    if (!recv_file_len(sock, &filesize)) { return false; }
    printf("file size (From C# client) : %ld\n", filesize);
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        do {
            int num = min(filesize, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (!recv_raw(sock, buffer, num)) {
                return false;
            }
            int offset = 0;
            do
            {
                size_t written = fwrite(&buffer[offset], 1, num - offset, f); // the fatal error
                if (written < 1) { return false; }
                offset += written;
            } while (offset < num);
            filesize -= num;
        } while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There are only 4 parameters to `fwrite` function. 1 of them is hard coded. `&Buffer[]` can never be `NULL`. Did you verify the other 2 parameters for valid values? If not, first step should always be to run your program in a debugger and check values and program flow.
Also adding `NULL` check for function parameters would generally be a good start.

Comment: hey @Gerhardh thanks for letting me know , i noticed that for some reason my file is failing to open even tho it exists

Comment: Then the problem is in the code not shown here in the question. You can create another question to handle that if necessary.